# TikZ with sqrt( ) function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble using the sqrt function along with draw in TikZ. Here is a sample of my code with what's working and what's not.

What could the issue be?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\y{1};\draw ($0.5*(\y+4,\y-4)$) -- ($0.5*(\y,\y)$); %WORKS OK
\def\y{1};\draw ($0.5*(\y+4,\y-4)$) -- ($0.5*(\y+{sqrt(\y)},\y)$); %DOES NOT WORK!
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

UPDATE: I found that the following variation of the code works, though I have no idea what was wrong with the previous code

```
   \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,patterns}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\y{1};\draw ($0.5*(\y+4,\y-4)$) -- ($0.5*(\y,\y)$); %WORKS OK
    \def\y{1};\draw ($0.5*(\y+4,\y-4)$) -- ($0.5*(\y,\y)+sqrt(\y)*(1,0)$); %WORKS OK!
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know the details of the parsing, but you need `({\y+sqrt(\y)},\y)`, i.e. the braces surround the entire x-coordinate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The expressions in the pair are absorbed as macro arguments, but first the pair has to be recognized: with

```
$0.5*(\y+sqrt(\y),\y)$
```

the first `)` would be mistaken as the end of the pair, which it isn't. So we need to keep it “hidden” to the parser:

```
$0.5*({\y+sqrt(\y)},\y)$
```

With `\y+{sqrt(\y)}` the first coordinate would have invalid tokens, namely the braces. To the contrary, when the pair is split into components from `$0.5*({\y+sqrt(\y)},\y)$` the first part would be `\y+sqrt(\y)`, because TeX strips off a set of unneeded braces after looking for an argument.